# Localize Form Commands

Tags: codenameone

In the Designer I'm able to sync UI with my localization data file. But it doesn't create any entry for my Form Commands.
Is there a way to do it in the designer? Or should I manually create Form commands in order to be able to localize their text?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a localized string with the name of the form command. The tool detects some cases when it generates the localization stubs but doesn't detect everything so you need to do some of the work manually.

Comment: You can now edit the developer guide directly in the wiki: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/wiki/ I'm not really sure where something like this will fit though.

Comment: I just add some code samples on the Localization part of that page : https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/wiki/Miscellaneous-Features